# Delete object on Realm, changes order of objects

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Hi I am using realm for first time and trying to delete object, delete works properly but it changes order of objects (it deletes the object, and last object in the list comes at index of deleted object). If anyone has experienced the same, please explain.

Comment: Not familiar with Realm, but I guess this group of objects is a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)), which is unordered and you should not rely on the order. A common solution to this is to query the objects sorted or sort them when you get them (usually this ordering happens on the id column in a database).

Comment: Realm object when you fetch is unordered as i know, and you should sort them after you fetched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects within a Realm are not inherently ordered. If you want them to be in a specific order, you must either sort on a property that gives them that order, or store them in an `RLMArray`/`List` property, which is an ordered type.

Answer (score 0):

I got an Idea for your situation. And I did it in my project and it worked perfectly. The idea is:

1. Get all object from Realm database.
2. Put it in another Array which is not a Realm Type.
3. You modify whatever you want with that Array which you have just created.
4. Delete all object from Ream database.
5. Save all object from Array to Realm database.

P/s: It worked also with Coredata.